# Unity Custom Drop Down selection for Arrays C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dropdown, unity-editor, unity3d-editor

I am trying to simplify selection of prefabs in a wave system.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WaveList : MonoBehaviour
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class Wave
    {
        public int waveCount;
        public string[] enemies;
        public int[] enemyLVL;
        public float[] delay;
    }

    public Wave[] waves;
}
```

I am trying to have a drop down menu in the Unity editor to choose the value of each enemy in
"enemies" via drop down menu.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: This would require a [Custom `PropertyDrawer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-PropertyDrawers.html) for your class ... where do you get the available values from?

Comment: I would like to have an array that I can add to with time,, will set it up based on the solution

Answer (score 4):

Usually your question is pretty broad and requires a lot of time.

However I kind of love Unity Editor scripting and honestly it is extremely complex and a bit hard to get in so consider this a little jump start into Editor scripting ;)

---

What you want to achieve requires four things:

- A field to store the available values
- A way to fill these available values
- An additional field to store the currently selected value
- [Custom `PropertyDrawer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-PropertyDrawers.html) for implementing the [`EditorGUI.Popup`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUI.Popup.html)

Editor scripting can get as complex as one wishes :D So I will only implement a very basic one. I hope this is a good start point for your needs:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif

public class WaveList : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Wave
    {
        public int waveCount;
        public string[] enemies;
        // Additional field for storing the currently selected enemy index
        public int selectedEnemy;
        public int[] enemyLVL;
        public float[] delay;

#if UNITY_EDITOR
        [CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(Wave))]
        private class WavePropertyDrawer : PropertyDrawer
        {
            // This will be generated during the OnGUI call
            // Maybe not the cleanest way but it works for now ;)
            private float height;
            private string[] availableEnemies;

            // This method is required so other property drawers (like the Wave[] waves)
            // know how much space to reserve for drawing this property
            public override float GetPropertyHeight(SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
            {
                return height + EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;
            }

            // Draw the property inside the given rect
            public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
            {
                // reset the height
                height = 0;

                // Using BeginProperty / EndProperty on the parent property means that    
                // prefab override logic works on the entire property.
                EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);
                {
                    // Get the rect for where to draw the label/foldout
                    var labelRect = new Rect(position.x, position.y, position.width, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight);
                    position.y += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;
                    height += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;

                    // Draw the foldout
                    property.isExpanded = EditorGUI.Foldout(labelRect, property.isExpanded, property.displayName);
                    if (property.isExpanded)
                    {
                        // indent children for better readability
                        EditorGUI.indentLevel++;
                        {
                            // Get serialized Properties
                            var serializedWaveCount = property.FindPropertyRelative(nameof(waveCount));
                            var serializedEnemies = property.FindPropertyRelative(nameof(enemies));
                            var serializedSelectedEnemy = property.FindPropertyRelative(nameof(selectedEnemy));
                            var serializedEnemyLVL = property.FindPropertyRelative(nameof(enemyLVL));
                            var serializedDelay = property.FindPropertyRelative(nameof(delay));

                            // Calculate rects
                            var waveCountHeight = EditorGUI.GetPropertyHeight(serializedWaveCount);
                            var waveCountRect = new Rect(position.x, position.y, position.width, waveCountHeight);
                            position.y += waveCountHeight;
                            height += waveCountHeight;

                            var enemiesHeight = EditorGUI.GetPropertyHeight(serializedEnemies, true);
                            var enemiesRect = new Rect(position.x, position.y, position.width, enemiesHeight);
                            position.y += enemiesHeight;
                            height += enemiesHeight;

                            var selectedEnemyRect = new Rect(position.x, position.y, position.width, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight);
                            position.y += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;
                            height += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;

                            var enemeiesLevelHeight = EditorGUI.GetPropertyHeight(serializedEnemyLVL, true);
                            var enemeiesLVLRect = new Rect(position.x, position.y, position.width, enemeiesLevelHeight);
                            position.y += enemeiesLevelHeight;
                            height += enemeiesLevelHeight;

                            var delayHeight = EditorGUI.GetPropertyHeight(serializedDelay, true);
                            var delayRect = new Rect(position.x, position.y, position.width, delayHeight);
                            position.y += delayHeight;
                            height += delayHeight;

                            // Draw Fields
                            availableEnemies = new string[serializedEnemies.arraySize];
                            for (var i = 0; i < serializedEnemies.arraySize; i++)
                            {
                                availableEnemies[i] = serializedEnemies.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i).stringValue;
                            }

                            EditorGUI.PropertyField(waveCountRect, serializedWaveCount);
                            EditorGUI.PropertyField(enemiesRect, serializedEnemies, true);
                            if (serializedEnemies.arraySize == 0)
                            {
                                serializedSelectedEnemy.intValue = -1;
                            }

                            serializedSelectedEnemy.intValue = EditorGUI.Popup(selectedEnemyRect, serializedSelectedEnemy.displayName, serializedSelectedEnemy.intValue, availableEnemies);
                            EditorGUI.PropertyField(enemeiesLVLRect, serializedEnemyLVL, true);
                            EditorGUI.PropertyField(delayRect, serializedDelay, true);
                        }
                        EditorGUI.indentLevel--;
                    }
                }
                EditorGUI.EndProperty();
            }
        }
#endif
    }

    public Wave[] waves;
}
```

So later in order to get the actual selected enemy you would access

```
var enemy = someWave.enemies[someWave.selectedEnemy];
```

---

now you can add, edit and remove `enemies` and then select a specific one via dropdown
[image]

---

As to your question of how to define the available `enemies` globally for all waves:

You should probably move the available array(s) into the `WaveList` class and define them only once there like.

Again this here will work for now but is quite dirty

```
public class WaveList : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string[] availableEnemies;
}
```

Then in the `Wave` only store the selected index like

```
[Serializable]
public class Wave
{
    public int waveCount;
    public int selectedEnemy;
    public int[] enemyLVL;
    public float[] delay;

    ...
```

Then in the property drawer instead of

```
var serializedEnemies = property.FindPropertyRelative(nameof(enemies));
```

You would rather get it directly from the `WaveList` class using

```
var serializedEnemies = property.serializedObject.FindProperty(nameof(WaveList.availableEnemies));
```

---

**Note: Typing on the phone but I hope the idea gets clear**

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for your time.
is it possible to have each element in Enemies[] be a drop down choice from one array that all waves take from? Basically, I am trying to make it easy and fast to select the enemies in each wave. Dragging and dropping into the array becomes a nightmare when you have 100+ waves

Comment: @CodingNoob_Help as said you will need a way of filling in the available enemy values ... where you take these from is up to you. You could e.g. have the array itself being placed in the `WaveList` class and also implement a `CustomEditor` for this one where you inject the array into all items in `Waves` ...